# CSS: Box+text over image

Tags: html, css, overlay, z-index

Firstly, I would like to show you a image(made in paint).

[image]

Okay "current" is what I have now. I want to place a box over the image to the right, with black background, and then have text inside this box.

I tried myself using z-index and so, but without any success. Here's what I tried:

```
<div> <!-- start div for image -->
  <img style="z-index: -1;" src="1.jpg" width="860" height="240"> <!-- the image -->
</div> <!-- end div -->
<div style="z-index: 1; width: 300px; background: #000; position: relative;">
  <div style="margin: auto;">
    text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

but this didnt turn out any good. How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/QGMPB/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    <div id="text">text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    position:relative; /* make this relative to have the inner div absolute without     breaking out */
    width: 200px;  /* fix the width or else it'll be the entire page's width */
    background: silver; 
    border: 1px solid grey
}

#text {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 40px; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    background: black; 
    color:white
}
```

Comment: And that's how to do it still keeping that img element! :)

Comment: Yeah, your code is exactly the same except for the img tags. Just depends on the situation which of the two is better :)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is messy and overcomplicated for such a simple issue, you can simplify it a lot by only using two elements. The simpler the better.

Please specify if you need the `<img>` tag.

HTML:

```
<div id="golf_course">
    <div class="text_wrap_right">
        text text text text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#golf_course
{
    background-image: url(http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2006/12/13/491548/ThaiGolfCourse.JPG);
    background-position: 0 -200px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 259px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.text_wrap_right
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}
```

And an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/WQT6G/

Comment: div-ification is not a clean solution, especially when appropriate tags exist

Comment: @Karem then Litso's answer is for you.

Comment: all browser can support new elements, even IE with html5shiv. If a technology should be finished before being used then I would not even use CSS 2.1 (not completely supported by ALL browser).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a simple and more semantic HTML5 solution

HTML:

```
<figure>
  <img src="..." />
  <figcaption>text text text ... </figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
figure {
  position : relative;
  z-index  : 1;
  width    : 860px;
  height   : 240px;
}

figcaption {
  position : absolute;
  z-index  : 1;
  top      : 0;
  right    : 0;
  width    : 200px;
  height   : 240px;
  background : #000;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, figcaption is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` to overlap 2 divs. You have to play with `left` and `top` properties to adjust its position.

```
 <div style="position:absolute"> <!-- start div for image -->
    <img style="z-index: -1;" src="1.jpg" width="860" height="240"> <!-- the image -->
    </div> <!-- end div -->
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 1; width: 300px; background: #000; position: relative; left:3%; top:85%">
    <div style="margin: auto;">text text text</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that text div inside the div that contains the image.. then set top and right to 0px and position absolute. take some hints from here: http://jsfiddle.net/U25XQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how this can be done, please let me know if it is not what you mean: [Example](http://www.flyingpie.nl/overlay.html).

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only works for positioned elements (`position: (absolute|fixed|relative)`). So you have to position your elements. For example

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 0; height: 100px; width: 300px;"> 
<img src="http://w3schools.com/images/w3cert.gif" />
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: 1; width: 200px; background: #000; position: absolute; left: 100px; color: #fff;">
<div style="margin: auto;">text text text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

For writing text over image you put image in background style and alt text like this-

```
<img scr="" alt="text"/>
<style>
.img{background-image:url('IMAGE_URL'); }
</style>
```